# Android Compose, How to play animated webp only once with coil?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, webp, coil

I was successful show animated webp using coil on image composable.
However, my goal is to only run this animated webp once.
Now it is repeating infinitely.
Is there a way?

Is my code.

[animated webp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmOP4.gif)

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    val resourceAnimated =
        "https://www.bandisoft.com/honeycam/help/file_format/sample.webp"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    MyApp()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    private fun MyApp() {
        val imageLoader = ImageLoader.Builder(this)
            .components {
                if (SDK_INT >= 28) {
                    add(ImageDecoderDecoder.Factory())
                } else {
                    add(GifDecoder.Factory())
                }
            }
            .build()

        val painter = rememberAsyncImagePainter(
            model = resourceAnimated,
            imageLoader = imageLoader,
        )

        Test(painter)
    }

    @Composable
    private fun Test(painter: AsyncImagePainter) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)) {
            Image(
                painter = painter, contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: yes. first add "implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-gif:2.2.2")" in gradle, and just use `repeatCount()` of ImageRequest.Builder extension function

Answer (score 4):

You can animate webp only once in coil.

Use this extension function

```
Image(painter =  rememberAsyncImagePainter(ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
                 .data(data= "your image url")
                 .repeatCount(0)
                 .build())
)
```